# Trying to make a conversion tool with an HTML button

Tags: javascript, html

I use JSfiddle to write some HTML and JS. When I write a number into one of the text areas and press the button, nothing happens. What is wrong with the code. PS: I am relatively new to JavaScript so sorry if I am doing this the wrong way.

HTML code:

```
Liter
<br>
<textarea></textarea>
<br> Gallon
<br>
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<button onClick="myFunction()">
Convert!
</button>
```

Javascript code:

```
var l = getElementsByTagName("textArea")[0].innerHTML;
var g = getElementsByTagName("textArea")[1].innerHTML;

function myFunction() {
if (g == "") {
g.innerHTML = l * 3.78541;
    } else if (l == "") {
l.innerHTML = g / 3.78541;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Move the l and g declarations inside the function.

Comment: @j08691: No; he has the opposite problem.

Comment: @SLaks - Only if he fixes the code to refer to the elements and not the values, or at least what should be their values and not the innerHTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your console and first you'll see that `getElementsByTagName` is not defined. Instead, you need to write `document.getElementsByTagName`.

Next, change your `l` and `g` declarations to reference the element, not their contents. Remember, `innerHTML` is going to be blank when the program first starts running (and you won't be using that but I'll get to that later).

```
var l = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[0];
var g = document.getElementsByTagName('textarea')[1];
```

Finally, change your `g` and `l` comparisons to using `g.value` and `l.value`:

```
if (g.value == "") {
  ...
} else if (l.value == "") {
  ...
}
```

`.value` refers to the "value" of the `textarea` i.e, what's been written in it. So now you'll be checking their contents based on what they are at the time the function is run, not at the time the page begins. Also, you previously tried to set `.innerHTML` on `l` and `g`. This wouldn't have worked because you assigned `l` and `g` to `value`, that is a `string`. `.innerHTML` is a property on DOM elements. Don't forget to change your calculations so they use `.value` instead of `l` and `g` as well. Remember, you want the *value* of the textarea, not the element itself.

Finally, because of the way you're using `myFunction` you'll want to make sure the script is placed in the head and you move your `l` and `g` declarations into the function.

That will get you most of the way there. After you understand the difference between DOM elements and strings, the rest is simple debugging.

Comment: also, the function "myfunction()" is not defined. need to declare the function before calling it.

Comment: `innerHTML ` of textarea??

Comment: @charlietfl Ah! You caught me. I was fixing that when you wrote that comment.

Comment: @Mike C So I made the changes that you suggested (https://jsfiddle.net/nseemannrica/a5dcmay6/3/) And I still can't figure what's wrong with the code. I tried to make an HTML page and to put the JS into the head but it still didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @goldpotatos You're still assigning `g` and `l` to the values instead of the elements. Also, your JSFiddle is set to onLoad instead of in the head.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to make this answer easy to follow:

```
Liter
  <br>
    <textarea id='liter'></textarea>
  <br> 

Gallon
  <br>
     <textarea id="gallon"></textarea>
  <br>

<button onClick="myFunction()"> Convert! </button>
```

Using `id` will help with scalability, and reduce confusion.

```
function myFunction() {

  var l = document.getElementById('liter');
  var liter = l.value;

  var g = document.getElementById("gallon");
  var gallon = g.value;

  if (gallon == "") {
    g.value = liter * 3.78541;
  } 

  else if (liter == "") {
    l.value = gallon / 3.78541;
  }

}
```

I've used this method before, and it is the easiest way I understand it.

You were really close to the right answer, just a few syntax things, honestly. Hope this helps you!